# Differences in probA, probB values between sklearn and libsvm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I'm digging into SVMs and Platt Scaling and I can't get through some differences I get in the values of `probA`, `probB` when considering sklearn `SVC(probability=True)`, the `_sigmoid_calibration()` method used to apply [Platt Scaling in CalibratedClassifierCV](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/calibration.py#L744) and `libsvm` directly.

Premises:

- AFAIK `SVC(probability=True)` is implemented with the internal Platt scaling routine of `libsvm`; though,
  I suspect some differences wrt `libsvm` may arise eg from differences in random number generations rules (see
  [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/LIBSVM_CHANGES) for reference).
- `_sigmoid_calibration()` should be coherent with `libsvm`; indeed, with [this PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/17856), libsvm-like
  calibration procedure was added (readjusted, actually, I guess) to `CalibratedClassifierCV(ensemble=False)`. Moreover, by looking at tests performed
  on the calibration module ([this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/tests/test_calibration.py#L372) in particular),
  it is clear that `_sigmoid_calibration()` is fully coherent with `libsvm` in the computation of `probA`, `probB`.
- I am not familiar with `libsvm`, therefore I might be neglecting something in the problem definition below.

This said, here is the snippet showing such differences I can't get through of. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.calibration import _sigmoid_calibration

from libsvm.svmutil import *
from libsvm import *

X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

mask = (y == 0) | (y == 1)
X = X[mask, :]
y = y[mask]  
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) 

model = SVC(probability=True, random_state=42, gamma='auto')
model.fit(X,y)
```

- `probA`, `probB` outputted by `SVC(probability=True)`

  ```
   model.probA_, model.probB_   # (array([-4.50114382]), array([-0.29587261]))
  ```
- `probA`, `probB` obtained via the calibration module

  ```
   dec_fun = model.decision_function(X)
   probaA, probaB = _sigmoid_calibration(dec_fun, y)
   probaA, probaB   # (-4.426391129899554, -0.2173222213684269)
  ```
- `libsvm` output

  ```
   np.random.seed(42)
   prob = svm_problem(y, X)
   param = svm_parameter('-s 0 -t 2 -c 1 -b 1')
   libsvm_model = svm_train(prob, param)
   libsvm_model.probA.contents.value, libsvm_model.probB.contents.value # (-4.6378404214097, -0.4000020264023851)
  ```